# Check whether a Kafka topic exists in Python

Tags: python, bash, apache-kafka

I want to create a [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) topic if it does not already exist. I know how to create a topic via the bash, but I don't know how to check whether it exists.

```
topic_exists = ??????
if not topic_exists:
    subprocess.call([os.path.join(KAFKABIN, 'kafka-topics.sh'),
        '--create',  
        '--zookeeper', '{}:2181'.format(KAFKAHOST),
        '--topic', str(self.topic), 
        '--partitions', str(self.partitions),
        '--replication-factor', str(self.replication_factor)])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `--list (List all available topics)` option for `kafka-topics.sh` and see if `self.topic` exists in the `topics` array, as shown below.

Depending on the number of topics you have this approach might be a bit heavy. If this is the case, you might be able to get away with using `--describe (List details for the given topics)` which will *likely* return empty if the topic doesn't exist. I haven't thoroughly tested this, so I can't say for sure how solid this solution (`--describe`) is, but it might be worth it for you to investigate a bit further.

```
wanted_topics = ['host_updates_queue', 'foo_bar']

topics = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(KAFKABIN, 'kafka-topics.sh'),
        '--list',
        '--zookeeper', '{}:2181'.format(KAFKAHOST)])

for wanted in wanted_topics:
    if wanted in topics:
        print '\'{}\' topic exists!'.format(wanted)
    else:
        print '\'{}\' topic does NOT exist!'.format(wanted)

    topic_desc = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(KAFKABIN, 'kafka-topics.sh'),
        '--describe',
        '--topic', wanted,
        '--zookeeper', '{}:2181'.format(KAFKAHOST)])

    if not topic_desc:
        print 'No description found for the topic \'{}\''.format(wanted)
```

OUTPUT:

```
root@dev:/opt/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1# ./t.py
'host_updates_queue' topic exists!
'foo_bar' topic does NOT exist!
No description found for the topic 'foo_bar'
```

There is also a [Broker Configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) available so you don't have to take any of these steps:

> auto.create.topics.enable | true  | Enable auto creation of topic on the server. If this is set to true then attempts to produce data or fetch metadata for a non-existent topic will automatically create it with the default replication factor and number of partitions.

I would take this approach if possible.

Note that you should set topic configs (`server.properties`) on your broker for `num.partitions` and `default.replication.factor` to match your settings in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, a straight-forward solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ThS Accidentally quoted the wrong Broker config. I fixed the post to quote  `auto.create.topics.enable`, the correct config to accomplish this. Note that the default is `true`, so you probably do not have to do anything :)

Answer (score 9):

Another nice way is with python kafka module:

```
kafka_client = kafka.KafkaClient(kafka_server_name)
server_topics = kafka_client.topic_partitions

if topic_name in server_topics:
   your code....
```

> kafka_client.topic_partitions returns list of topics.

Comment: Been looking for a way to do this for a looong time. Not apparent from the docs, imo.

Comment: @sshow please write here what you were looking for, so that the next person who had your issue will find it faster :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I needed a way to fail early if the topic didn't exist, because currently (kafka-python 1.3.5) the consumer consumes 100% CPU due to an infinite loop when the consumer starts polling a non-existant topic.

Comment: I also want list of topics and hence I tried this code but I am getting error as - 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'topic_partitions' can anyone help me why this is so

Answer (score 3):

Use [kafka-python consumer](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.topics) api for this.

```
import kafka 
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(group_id='test', bootstrap_servers=your_server_list) 
new_topics = set(wanted_topics)-set(consumer.topics())
for topic in new_topics:
    create(topic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `KafkaAdminClient` from kafka api. Not docummented but a method `list_topics` exists !

Answer (score 0):

Another way, If you are using `KafkaAdminClient` We can get the set of topics.

```
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient
admin = KafkaAdminClient(**kafka_admin_client_config)
kafka_topics = admin._client.cluster.topics()
```